# Express $\tan{\theta}$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\mu_s$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statics

> **Problem:** Determine the least angle $\theta$ where equilibrium is possible. Express $\tan{\theta}$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\mu_s$
>
> [image]

**Attempt:** I started of with drawing out all the acting forces:

[image]

I know that $\tan{\theta}=\frac{h}{x_1+x_2}$ so I need to express $h$ and $x_1,x_2$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\mu_s.$ I know the following:

$$x_1+x_2 = l\cos{\theta} \\ h=l\sin{\theta} \\ x_1=h\tan{\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \\ x_2 = l\cos{\theta}-h\tan{\left(\alpha-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$

and for the forces:

$$N_{Ax}=N_A\sin{\alpha} \\
N_{Ay}=N_A\cos{\alpha} \\
F_f=N_B\mu_s$$

$\sum F_x = 0 = N_{Ax}-F_f = N_A\sin{\alpha}-N_B \mu_s \Rightarrow N_A = \frac{N_B\mu_s}{\sin{alpha}}.$

$\sum F_y = 0 = N_{Ay} - mg + N_B = N_A\cos{\alpha}-mg-N_B \Rightarrow N_A=\frac{mg-N_B}{\cos{\alpha}}.$

Setting the above equal gives

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    N_A & = & \frac{mg\mu_s}{\mu_s\cos{\alpha}+\sin{\alpha}} \\
    N_B & = & \frac{mg\sin{\alpha}}{mu_s\cos{\alpha}+\sin{alpha}} \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Aand now I don't really know what to do with this information.

Comment: Please read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) carefully. Note that [showing your on workings is not sufficient](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic); you need to ask about the underlying concepts that you're confused about.

Comment: I thought I was clear about needing to express $h$ and $x_1,x_2$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\mu_s.$ And by the way, who told you this is a homeworkquestion? I'm simply studying for my exam after Christmas, We don't have "homework" in universities here in my country, we simply study for an exam. Quite annoying that one can't even ask a question about physics in a physics forum without having to go through a hassle with some bureaucratic moderator.

Comment: @Parseval: if we didn't put the 'brakes' on homework style questions, we'd be inundated with them. As it stands we still are. Nothing to do with 'bureaucracy', just common sense. Voted to close. Other forums don't have the same policy, so try there?

Comment: This is still not a homework. And I've made it clear where I'm stuck. I don't see the problem?

Comment: Explained by Emilio. We call them *homework style* questions. It doesn't literally by homework. Check the policy.

Comment: @Parseval If you wish, we can discuss such problems on this chatroom: [PSS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies).